# Cause of form to not submit on first click, works on second click?

Tags: javascript, html, ssl, smtp, contact-form

I have tried to debug this myself with no success. Form used to work on the first load without TSS. However adding SSL to the server, causes the form to not work first time but works on the second form fill and submit.

In order of actions:

First click: Fill in the form and press send. The form resets and the page goes to the top. - (no user message or email).

Second click: Fill in the form and press send. The form alerts users with "Success, hope to speak to you soon!" - (I also receive an email).

```
<section id="contact" class="contact">
            <div class="container pt-2 pb-2" data-aos="fade-up ">
                <div class="section-title ">
                    <h2>Contact</h2>
                </div>
                <div class="form-wrapper">
                    <form onsubmit="sendEmail(); reset();">
                        <h3>Get in Touch</h3>
                        <input type="text" id="name" placeholder="Your Name" required>
                        <input type="text" name="phone" id="phone" placeholder="Phone no." required>
                        <input type="email" id="email" placeholder="Your Email (Must be valid)" required>
                        <textarea name="message" id="message" rows="4" placeholder="Message here."></textarea>
                        <button type="submit">Send</button>
                    </form>
                </div>
            </div>
        </section>
```

```
 <script src="https://smtpjs.com/v3/smtp.js"></script>
    <!-- Aware that this isnt safe, to use as password is shown etc. 
This is used as a temporary fix to allow users to contact me.-->
    <script>
        //sad to do it this way, but it works. Just not first time.
        function sendEmail() {
            Email.send({
                Host: "smtp.someDomain.com",
                Username: "someUsername",
                Password: "somePassword",
                To: 'toSomeEmail',
                From: document.getElementById("email").value,
                Subject: "New Contact Form Submission",
                Body: "Name: " + document.getElementById("name").value +
                    "\n" +
                    "Phone: " + document.getElementById("phone").value +
                    "\n" +
                    "Email: " + document.getElementById("email").value +
                    "\n" +
                    "Message: " + document.getElementById("message").value
            }).then(function(message) {
                alert("Success, hope to speak to you soon!");
            });
        }
    </script>
```

There are no any errors however there is a change in the console:

**Images are uploaded via Gyazo (Screen capture software)**

[First Click "Send" on Contact form Console Image](https://gyazo.com/171d2293016b0b7ff89c88eb04b6f22e.png)

[After first click "Send" Console Image](https://gyazo.com/daf14fcc5123bda3dec8be40963886c1)

Is there any way I can load the contact form on the first load so it can work the first time, any help would be appreciated?

Comment: I think that the problem is that you are not preventing the form to be submited

Comment: @R4ncid it works after pressing send the first time and the form resets. But initially when you go on the site it doesn’t work.